# imported 3D objects are not casting shadows with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently wrapping my brain around three.js and I've imported 3d model I made in C4D via the three.OBJMTLLoader successfully, but I can't get the object to cast a shadow. I've used object.castShadow = true but its not working but I can get geometry created in three.js to cast a shadow so I know the scene is setup ok.

The test scene is currently here: http://kirkd.co.uk/dev/ and has now been updated with the fix suggested below.

The code is below, if someone could kindly point out either what I'm doing wrong or even if imported objects can cast shadows then I'd be eternally grateful.

Ta.

```
        <script>


        var container;

        var controls;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000);
            camera.position.z = 500;
            camera.position.y = 500;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );


            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
            spotLight.position.set( 500, 1000, 500 );
            spotLight.castShadow = true;

            spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
            spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
            scene.add( spotLight );

            var companion = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            companion.load( 'companion2.obj', 'companion.mtl', function ( object ) {
                object.position.set(0,-20,0);
                object.scale.set( 0.8, 0.8, 0.8 );
                object.castShadow = true;
                scene.add( object );
            });


            var floorGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1000,4,1000);
            var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
            var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
            floor.position.x=0;
            floor.position.y=-130;
            floor.position.z=0;
            floor.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add(floor);

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry);
            scene.add( mesh );
            mesh.position.set(-100,200,10);
            mesh.castShadow = true;

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
            renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
            spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

            var step=0;
            render();
        };

        function render() {
          camera.lookAt(scene.position);
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }


      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your object has child meshes, each of which needs to have `castShadow` set to `true`.

In your loader callback, add this:

```
object.traverse( function( node ) { if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { node.castShadow = true; } } );
```

three.js r.66

Comment: Nice one, it works. I'd just like to get my head around this so I understand it properly. Is the problem that the .obj file isn't the object, it's that the .obj file houses the meshs and I can have multiple 3d objects within the .obj file. Is that right?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file for detailed info about the OBJ format.

Comment: I get what an obj is, C4D pumps them out pretty badly so I use a plugin, but within the obj you can have multiple meshs. I've produced content for games before but i've always handed those over the the developers so I'm just trying to understand the relationship between the imported obj and three.js. Theres only a single mesh within the obj but that counts as a child of the file.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work on a mesh resulting of json load ?

Comment: @Astrak You need to make a new post if you have a question.