# No shadows even when shadow is enabled

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have written the following code to get the shadow of the stanford dragon on a plane. But I am not getting it. I have enabled shadow by object and plane to receive shadow. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/shaders/ConvolutionShader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/shaders/FXAAShader.js"></script>

    <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/postprocessing/BloomPass.js"></script>

        <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( window.innerWidth === 0 ) { window.innerWidth = parent.innerWidth; window.innerHeight = parent.innerHeight; }

            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var group;
            var depthMaterial, depthTarget, composer;
            var object;
            init();
            animate();



            function init() {
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000,0.1));
                renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
                renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;   
                renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                //camera.position.x = 100;
                camera.position.y = 100;
                camera.position.z = 100;
                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(150,150);
                var planeMaterial =    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xaaaaaa});
                var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);
                plane.receiveShadow  = true;
                plane.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
                plane.position.x=0;
                plane.position.y=0;
                plane.position.z=0;
                 // add the plane to the scene
                scene.add(plane);
                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
                spotLight.position.set( -80, 60, -10 );
                spotLight.shadowMapWidth =2048;
                spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
                spotLight.castShadow = true;
                spotLight.shadowMapEnabled = true;
                scene.add( spotLight );
                //Camera




                // model

                var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                    }
                };

                var onError = function ( xhr ) {
                };


                THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

                var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                loader.load( 'dragon.obj', 'dragon.mtl', function ( object ) {

                    object.position.y = 0;
                    object.position.x = 0;
                    object.position.z = 10;
                    object.castShadow=true;
                    object.receiveShadow= true;
                    object.scale.set(4,4,4); 
                    scene.add( object );

                }, onProgress, onError );

                //

                var depthShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normal" ];
                var depthUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( depthShader.uniforms );


                depthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { fragmentShader: depthShader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: depthShader.vertexShader, uniforms: depthUniforms } );
                depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending;
                // postprocessing

                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
                composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ));

                depthTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat } );

                var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.SSAOShader );
                effect.uniforms[ 'tDepth' ].value = depthTarget;
                effect.uniforms[ 'size' ].value.set(  window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                effect.uniforms[ 'cameraNear' ].value = camera.near;
                effect.uniforms[ 'cameraFar' ].value = camera.far;
                effect.uniforms[ 'aoClamp' ].value = 0.9;
                effect.uniforms[ 'onlyAO' ].value=0;
                effect.renderToScreen = true;
                composer.addPass( effect );


                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            }
            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );


                scene.overrideMaterial = depthMaterial;
                renderer.render( scene, camera, depthTarget );

                scene.overrideMaterial = null;
                composer.render();


            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me in finding out in what I have done wrongly. I am comparatively new to JavaScript also.
Another thing I wanted to add to the information above is that it works only with firefox and not chrome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution to the problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895120/imported-3d-objects-are-not-casting-shadows-with-three-js).

Comment: I doubt that answer holds a solution. I have this problem using the composer. Does the problem also show up when you are not using SSAO shader?? Try disabling it. Alternately try disabling recieveShadow for that object. Self shadowing seems to be an issue with current three.js

Comment: The answer holds. It worked in my case.